# jedi-vim cannot initialize python

Tags: python, jedi-vim

I installed jedi-vim with Pathogen. I want it to use my anaconda python which is python 3.6 and not my system python.
I have edited my $PATH variable in my .bashrc file to:

```
export PATH="/opt/anaconda/3-5.0.0.1/bin:$PATH"
```

and I have pip installed jedi for anaconda python.

When I try to edit a python file, I get the following error:

```
Error: jedi-vim failed to initialize Python: jedi#setup_python_imports: ImportError: No module named jedi (in function jedi#ini
t_python..<SNR>24_init_python..jedi#setup_python_imports, line 32). See :messages and/or :JediDebugInfo for more information.
```

Here is the output of `:verbose JediDebugInfo`:

```
##### Global Python

Using Python version 2 to access Jedi.
 - global sys.executable: `/opt/anaconda/3-5.0.0.1/bin/python`
 - global sys.version: `2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56), [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]`
 - global site module: `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.pyc`
```

some more info if it can help:

```
which python
/opt/anaconda/3-5.0.0.1/bin/python
which python2
/usr/bin/python2
which python3
/opt/anaconda/3-5.0.0.1/bin/python3
```

Comment: Finding answer to this question might be easier on [vi stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Was answered in https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/1008

@Tabataba I assume you are the same guy asking the same question. Please don't ask the same question in two separate places in the future. One should be enough.